# Is there a word for pleasing numbers?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives, neologisms

Similar to how *euphonic* describes words that sound pleasing, is there a word for numbers that feel pleasing and comfortable? Like 12:34, $20, or 7.17? I ask because it seems to be an important concept in marketing, storytelling, and even culture.

I can think to construct *eunumeric*, which I find euphonic too, but I've never seen that anywhere. :)

EDIT: Would like to open again because someone claimed this question was opinion-based, but I added a comment explaining why I think that’s incorrect. The definition is not opinion-based, but it does describe a subjective concept.

Comment: Euphonic  can be applied to numbers too

Comment: That’s true but I mean the quality of enjoying the number, instead of the way it sounds. For example, I would say that 12:34:56.789 is an extremely pleasing timestamp, but that time does not sound euphonic at all.

Comment: Just because you haven't seen *eunumeric* anywhere doesn't mean you can't use it!

Comment: That’s true! And it does a good job of sounding like what it is.

Comment: I’m not sure “it does a good job of sounding like what it is”. I’d have to guess about what is might mean..but that’s probably me. Anyway if you use a brand new just invented term, make sure readers can understand it.

Comment: @HaumedRahmani - sorry, but in what sense *12:34:56.789* is an extremely pleasing timestamp. This is an opinion based issue.

Comment: As to retail, an amount might be good to use as a price if it is a [price point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_point).

Comment: Yes, that timestamp you mention seems *visually* pleasing more than numerically pleasing. In which case you're looking for 'aesthetic', perhaps. Initially I thought you were referring to a synesthetic experience.

Comment: The application of the word is definitely subjective, but its definition is not. Beauty is a subjective but well-defined concept. And again I wouldn't call that timestamp aesthetically pleasing, it's not the shapes of the glyphs that make it interesting, it's the relation between the digits. I'm not sure I've heard many great attempts at an answer here, and I think the question should still be open…

Comment: I voted to close this because I have a strong opinion that few people find numbers intrinsically pleasing. Some are more salient ( ... 98, 99, **100**, 101), a dozen, a gross, a million ...) but salience rather than pleasingness through familiarity is the main issue here. 'Favourite colours' makes more sense, and the two-word term is what is used.

Comment: Hmm an interesting point. You're right that there's often a salience or serendipity to it, and in that regard the right word might be *elegant*, which is used a lot in math and science already. But I don’t find it less significant than a favorite color, a favorite number is common. I personally love 5, and I’ve heard it joked as well that “there’s always 7 magic items to track down, never 4.” It's both an innate and a learned thing. This can have a lot to do with salience and aesthetics as well though so the boundaries gets blurry.

Comment: I was mainly looking for the difference between a disordered vs an elegant number, and that seems to explain it well, so I’m comfortable closing the issue!

Answer (score -1):

I liked the answers *elegant* and *salient*, but would love most to be able to use *eunumeric* someday if it ever catches on. :) Thanks everyone for the discussion!